# Expressing desire with a な-adj

Tags: conjugations

How can I conjugate na adjective to say "want". For example:
I want to hate - 嫌い　+　たい？

I want to not hate 嫌い　＋　たくない？

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't. たい form is only used with verbs. 嫌い, a な-adj, cannot be conjugated into たい. However, you can come up with phrases that are equivalent to what you're trying to express.

> 彼のことは嫌いになりたくない。
> I don't want to come to dislike him.

I also want to point out that 嫌う is indeed a verb,  <s>but I do not think it is ever used in 嫌いたくない. I could be wrong, as I am not a native speaker, but I have never seen it used that way.</s>  According to @naruto in the comments, 嫌いたくない also sounds natural, but is less common.

Comment: Thanks. How about 嫌わなくなりたい. Is that also a possible form?

Comment: 嫌いたくない makes perfect sense to me, although 嫌いになりたくない is more common.